# Blazor set value inside other component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, components, blazor

I'm building my page and I was wondering if I can make my life easier and put some simple custom Input boxes inside method and them pass reference to my values to them

```
<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-2">@Caption</label>
    <InputNumber class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="@Value"/>
</div>
<br />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like

```
<CustomInputNumber Caption="Price" Value="@Product.Price" />
```

It is possible to set value like that? Or pass object as reference? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about this is inheriting from inputbase and basically building your own input. Chrissainty has an excellent blog post about, which I think is much clearer then me citing half of what he already explains in that post.

https://chrissainty.com/building-custom-input-components-for-blazor-using-inputbase/

If however you really want to wrap the already existing inputcomponent, you could do it like this:

The component

```
<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-2">@Caption</label>
    <InputNumber class="form-control col-3" Value="Value" TValue="int" ValueChanged="HandleValueChanged" ValueExpression="(()=>Value)"  />
</div>
<br />

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    public void HandleValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(newValue);
    }
}
```

Usage like:

```
<ExampleComponent @bind-Value="ExampleValue"/>
```

Here you basically override the existing events that exist on a default inputfield. When the default component notices a change, you call your own valuechanged event to pass the event to it's parent.

Though again, I think the first solution is much cleaner.

Comment: This so much better than I expected, thank you alot

Comment: The InputNumber component must be nested within the EditForm component. It can't exist on its own. The above solution do not take it into account. Note that the Value  parameter should not be mutated by the component: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599#issuecomment-697588562

Comment: That's true @enet. But as that's the case for all standard input components, I didn't include it for brevity. Didn't know that about changing the Value parameter, So i'll quickly edit that!